# Flink job fails after 10 minutes from initialization

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm having problems with flink application fail.

This streaming job runs shortly after deploying on Yarn.

But is fails after some minutes with below error messages.

Can it be the evidence of high load in low performance yarn cluster?

- 1.5.0 flink and yarn single job
- Single node is equipped with 100GBytes RAM and 40 v-cores
- 48 Yarn node manager.
- 2 Kafka topic input ( 150GBytes/hour for each input stream. )
- 480 kafka partition.
- 10 flink slot per node manager

**From the beginning of the flink**

```
Log Type: jobmanager.log

Log Upload Time: Tue Jun 12 18:19:50 +0900 2018

Log Length: 10807897

2018-06-11 18:59:27,167 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-11 18:59:27,168 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Starting YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint (Version: 1.5.0, Rev:c61b108, Date:24.05.2018 @ 14:54:44 UTC)
2018-06-11 18:59:27,168 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  OS current user: irteam
2018-06-11 18:59:27,472 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-06-11 18:59:27,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: irteam
2018-06-11 18:59:27,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.161-b14
2018-06-11 18:59:27,536 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Maximum heap size: 66667 MiBytes
2018-06-11 18:59:27,537 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64
2018-06-11 18:59:27,537 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Hadoop version: 2.8.3
2018-06-11 18:59:27,537 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM Options:
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xmx75000m
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Djava.library.path=/home1/irteam/realtime-tools
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog.file=/naver/search-cluster/eye/var/logs/application_1528711080009_0002/container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000001/jobmanager.log
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:logback.xml
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Program Arguments: (none)
2018-06-11 18:59:27,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Class path[omit]
2018-06-11 18:59:27,539 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-11 18:59:27,539 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2018-06-11 18:59:27,542 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - YARN daemon is running as: irteam Yarn client user obtainer: irteam
2018-06-11 18:59:27,544 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: env.java.home, "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk"
2018-06-11 18:59:27,544 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: env.java.opts, "-Djava.library.path=/home1/irteam/realtime-tools"
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: high-availability.cluster-id, application_1528711080009_0002
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, 0.0.0.0
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 100000
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.network.request-backoff.max, 100000
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: containerized.taskmanager.env.JAVA_HOME, /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: internal.cluster.execution-mode, NORMAL
2018-06-11 18:59:27,545 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 480
2018-06-11 18:59:27,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 10
2018-06-11 18:59:27,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 100000
2018-06-11 18:59:27,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: containerized.master.env.JAVA_HOME, /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64
2018-06-11 18:59:27,558 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Setting directories for temporary files to: /home1/irteam/naver/search-cluster/eye/volume/nodemanager/usercache/irteam/appcache/application_1528711080009_0002
2018-06-11 18:59:27,570 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Starting YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.
2018-06-11 18:59:27,570 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Install default filesystem.
2018-06-11 18:59:27,636 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to irteam (auth:SIMPLE)
2018-06-11 18:59:27,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Initializing cluster services.
2018-06-11 18:59:27,654 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Trying to start actor system at chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524
2018-06-11 18:59:28,126 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2018-06-11 18:59:28,222 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
2018-06-11 18:59:28,322 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524]
2018-06-11 18:59:28,329 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524
2018-06-11 18:59:28,348 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Created BLOB server storage directory /home1/irteam/naver/search-cluster/eye/volume/nodemanager/usercache/irteam/appcache/application_1528711080009_0002/blobStore-c25d4d9d-4ddc-442d-8d5e-7bec36dca006
2018-06-11 18:59:28,349 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:45733 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000
2018-06-11 18:59:28,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,367 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore  - Initializing FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore: Storage directory /home1/irteam/naver/search-cluster/eye/volume/nodemanager/usercache/irteam/appcache/application_1528711080009_0002/executionGraphStore-63bcf196-410d-4d8c-8388-f270beb53555, expiration time 3600000, maximum cache size 52428800 bytes.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,388 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Created BLOB cache storage directory /home1/irteam/naver/search-cluster/eye/volume/nodemanager/usercache/irteam/appcache/application_1528711080009_0002/blobStore-02db740f-8c23-46e8-bb24-1f583b6a0b33
2018-06-11 18:59:28,395 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Upload directory /tmp/flink-web-8698d702-67fe-437c-b62e-78c2969bf770/flink-web-upload does not exist, or has been deleted externally. Previously uploaded files are no longer available.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,396 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Created directory /tmp/flink-web-8698d702-67fe-437c-b62e-78c2969bf770/flink-web-upload for file uploads.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,399 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Starting rest endpoint.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component log file: /naver/search-cluster/eye/var/logs/application_1528711080009_0002/container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000001/jobmanager.log
2018-06-11 18:59:28,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of main cluster component stdout file: /naver/search-cluster/eye/var/logs/application_1528711080009_0002/container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000001/jobmanager.out
2018-06-11 18:59:28,808 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Rest endpoint listening at chd004.eye.nfra.io:39794
2018-06-11 18:59:28,808 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - http://chd004.eye.nfra.io:39794 was granted leadership with leaderSessionID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2018-06-11 18:59:28,808 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Web frontend listening at http://chd004.eye.nfra.io:39794.
2018-06-11 18:59:28,817 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager at akka://flink/user/resourcemanager .
2018-06-11 18:59:28,902 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher at akka://flink/user/dispatcher .
2018-06-11 18:59:28,916 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                     - ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524/user/resourcemanager was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000000000000000000000000000
2018-06-11 18:59:28,917 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager  - Starting the SlotManager.
2018-06-11 18:59:29,161 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                     - Recovered 0 containers from previous attempts ([]).
2018-06-11 18:59:29,163 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy  - yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
2018-06-11 18:59:29,174 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Dispatcher akka.tcp://flink@chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524/user/dispatcher was granted leadership with fencing token 00000000000000000000000000000000
2018-06-11 18:59:29,174 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Recovering all persisted jobs.
2018-06-11 18:59:31,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Submitting job 5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc (LCS realtime data).
2018-06-11 18:59:31,130 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster at akka://flink/user/jobmanager_0 .
2018-06-11 18:59:31,136 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Initializing job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc).
2018-06-11 18:59:31,144 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Using restart strategy FixedDelayRestartStrategy(maxNumberRestartAttempts=3, delayBetweenRestartAttempts=30000) for LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc).
2018-06-11 18:59:31,148 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool at akka://flink/user/a6ffe322-07db-4282-a29c-0836ad26cd9f .
2018-06-11 18:59:31,165 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job recovers via failover strategy: full graph restart
2018-06-11 18:59:31,174 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Running initialization on master for job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc).
2018-06-11 18:59:31,174 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Successfully ran initialization on master in 0 ms.
2018-06-11 18:59:31,248 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Using application-defined state backend: File State Backend (checkpoints: 'file:/home1/irteam/apps/flink-1.4.0/checkpoint', savepoints: 'null', asynchronous: UNDEFINED, fileStateThreshold: -1)
2018-06-11 18:59:31,248 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Configuring application-defined state backend with job/cluster config
2018-06-11 18:59:31,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner           - JobManager runner for job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc) was granted leadership with session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 at akka.tcp://flink@chd004.eye.nfra.io:33524/user/jobmanager_0.
2018-06-11 18:59:31,260 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                  - Starting execution of job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc)
2018-06-11 18:59:31,261 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING.
2018-06-11 18:59:31,264 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/480) (98a01166bb2ac99dd301e4b60febbc45) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
```

**Near the timeout event which might cause flink job fails.**

```
2018-06-12 18:17:39,750 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.backpressure.StackTraceSampleCoordinator  - Cancelling sample 5589
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@chd023.eye.nfra.io:34783/user/taskmanager_0#-297572584]] after [15000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-12 18:17:39,770 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.backpressure.StackTraceSampleCoordinator  - Cancelling sample 5590
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@chd032.eye.nfra.io:34653/user/taskmanager_0#424015125]] after [15000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-12 18:17:51,270 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.backpressure.StackTraceSampleCoordinator  - Cancelling sample 5591
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@chd032.eye.nfra.io:34653/user/taskmanager_0#424015125]] after [15000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-12 18:17:55,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                     - The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017 timed out.
2018-06-12 18:17:55,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                     - Closing TaskExecutor connection container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017 because: The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017  timed out.
2018-06-12 18:17:55,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager  - Unregister TaskManager 525095d833344e8b205017666accd9c5 from the SlotManager.
2018-06-12 18:17:55,650 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Window(EventTimeSessionWindows(300000), NowTrigger, NowSessionProcessor) -> Sink: Unnamed (188/480) (f9ed2fc23d6ca5a364300864b60760af) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing TaskManager container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManagerInternal(SlotPool.java:1067)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManager(SlotPool.java:1050)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.onReceive(AkkaRpcActor.java:142)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2018-06-12 18:17:55,651 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job LCS realtime data (5f090c4f4287db062cee0996da5d5ffc) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing TaskManager container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManagerInternal(SlotPool.java:1067)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPool.releaseTaskManager(SlotPool.java:1050)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.onReceive(AkkaRpcActor.java:142)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2018-06-12 18:17:55,679 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/480) (98a01166bb2ac99dd301e4b60febbc45) switched from RUNNING to CANCELING.
```

Comment: The error in the log snippet originates from a REST handler and should not be the cause for your job failure. Could you share the complete cluster entrypoint logs with us to further debug your problem?

Comment: I updates log message and cluster information for new systems. It runs about 24 hours from the job submission but it also fails. Till I can send full log message to you for more details

Comment: Could you check the logs for the `TaskManager` `container_e08_1528711080009_0002_01_000017`. The logs show that the heartbeat timed out to this machine. Could it be that the container was simply killed? Flink should be able to recover from this if checkpointing is enabled.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Because check-pointing is disabled as far as we doesn't need to process data from the past pointer in Kafka.

Comment: I still don't want to read data from the last offset in checkpoint. Can I disable this behavior even in checkpoint enabled?

Comment: You can manually set a restart strategy on the `ExecutionConfig`: `env.getConfig().setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(20, Time.millis(1000L))`.